# Where to put .xib file inside framework project?

Tags: ios, xib, cocoa-touch

I lost half a day figuring this and I can't see a straight forward solution online.

I created an iOS CocoaTouch Framework. I have some private and public classes in it and it all works fine.
The ***problem*** is when I ***add .xib file inside that framework***.

Inside my framework I want to instantiate .xib file and the error I am getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/dino/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FEDECDC2-D4EA-441E-B53B-329A5B3DFB7A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/78CEC01F-4C36-4143-A7D6-DDE6CCAC801B/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'NUInAppMessageView''
```

I've heard that .xib files can not be contained inside static library but I think they should be able to be used inside the framework.

My framework target contains "Copy Bundle Resources" from before and this .xib file was automatically added when I created it inside framework project.

[image]

I've read on a few places that resources should be added in a separate .*bundle* target but there is no "bundle" option when creating new targets and I believe this is form the old static-library-days.

This is the code I am using to initialize my view (inside the framework):

```
NSBundle * frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]; // fine (not nil)

NUInAppMessageView *view = [[frameworkBundle loadNibNamed:@"NUInAppMessageView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject]; // <-- CRASH
```

I tried to break this into a more method calls and figured that Nib itself is getting created:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NUInAppMessageView"
                                bundle:frameworkBundle]; // fine (not nil)
NSArray *objects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil]; // <-- CRASH
```

I don't have ideas anymore. I tried with project Clean, deleting derived data but they don't seem to do the job.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The only obvious difference between your code and mine is that I loaded that nib from within the main code, not from within the framework code, but that was just an accident; it makes no difference. I just rewrote it so that I load the nib from within the framework code and it works fine too.

Comment: @matt I am going to delete everything and create fresh .xib. It could be that Xcode messed somewhere with cached settings. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't actually answer the question. Sometimes it helps just to be shown "yes this should work, you're not crazy". :)

Comment: @matt At least I can enjoy the weekend now and tackle this on Monday :)

Answer (score 17):

## Where to Put Nib Files within a Framework in iOS Project?

**Background to my answer:** 
I was trying to export some `UITableView` related implementation and it had `UITableViewCell` `.xib` files packed with it. And they turn into `.nib` files at the end! ;-) And I was referring to those Nib files as follows:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:customCellID owner:nil options:nil];
```

**Explanation:**
But here the thing I have done wrong is, I build a static Cocoa Touch Framework and try to use it within another Application. So at the run time what would become the `MainBundle`? Definitely my UITableView implementation trying to find out that Nib file for the customCellID in within the App's main bundle.

**Answer:**
So I altered my `UITableView` implementation's above code snippet as follows:

```
    NSString *frameworkBundleId = @"com.randika.MyFrameworkBundleIDHere";
    NSBundle *resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:frameworkBundleId];

    customCell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellID];
    if (customCell == nil) {
       NSArray *nibs = [resourcesBundle loadNibNamed:emptyCellID owner:nil options:nil];
       customCell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

And the framework I built out of my `UITableView` implementation didn't give the above error ever again! :-)

Hope this answer might be helpful to somebody out there!

Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Generic solution for controllers with .xib file

```
public extension UIViewController {

    //** loads instance from right framework bundle, not main bundle as UIViewController.init() does
    private static func genericInstance<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
        return T.init(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: Bundle(for: self))
    }

    public static func instance() -> Self {
        return genericInstance()
    }
}
```

Use as

```
YourViewController.instance()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way is just `self` referenceing the bundle.

```
 let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```