# iOS, swift container library which contains nibs?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm not sure if this can be done with frameworks.

I'm in the planning stage for an app written in swift. This will be one of my first ventures into swift.

How can I add nib files and asset catalogs to some kind of library which I can share among different applications?

Comment: You can pack them into bundle and ship with your framework/static lib

Comment: So the bundle goes into the framework ? What's a static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework is designed to store resources (nib's, images and etc) along with lib files.

Here is discussed framework vs static lib difference:
[Required Framework vs Static Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285145/required-framework-vs-static-library)

Check here how to add resources to framework: [Where to put .xib file inside framework project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942816/where-to-put-xib-file-inside-framework-project)